# Iniciar y parar un setInterval con onmouseover onmouseout

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Quiero iniciar un `setInterval` cuando el cursor este fuera del botón y cuando el cursor este sobre el boton parar el `setInterval`. Este código me ayudara para parar e iniciar un slider cuando un usuario lo este viendo. El código mostrado solo funciona una vez es decir se "para" el `setInterval` pero no inicia de nuevo

```js
var timer = null;
var i = 0;

function stop() {
  if (timer !== null) return;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    $("p").html(i);
  }, 1000);
};

function star() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  time = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onmouseover="star()" onmouseout="stop()">Start and Stop</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que puedes cambiar varias cosas:

1. Si quieres que el timer corra mientras se está fuera del botón lo ideal sería iniciarlo cuando se carga la página.
2. Si es así necesitas que tu start inicie el `setInterval` en el evento `mouseOut`, es decir que llame a la función `start`. Lo mismo para el `stop` pero con el otro evento.
3. No necesitas hacer un condicional para el `start` o el `stop` ya que los eventos no se disparan cuando se está dentro o fuera del botón (no es un `hover`), si no que se disparan cuando sales del objeto, lo cual ocurre una única vez.
4. No sé que hace tu variable `time`, pero no la necesitas.

```js
var timer = null;
var i = 0;

function stop() {
  clearInterval(timer);

};

function start() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    $("p").html(i);
  }, 1000);
}

start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="start()">Start and Stop</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias FRAN